# best way for javascript to access values from properties file in spring application

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, properties, spring-boot, configuration-files

What's the current best way for javascript to access values that are set in an external properties file?

For ex.  I want to set up a time out redirect with the session time configurable via a properties file. Is there an obvious way to do this that I'm missing?

I'm using spring boot with thymeleaf.

Answer (score 2):

You could inline Javascript code into your HTML using `th:inline`.

Consider the following:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var timeout = [[${app.timeout}]];
</script>
```

You'll have to create an class for the application's properties with getters and setters for the properties you'd like to access using the Thymeleaf's `${property}` syntax.